# How is this not a JSON object?

Tags: typescript

```
const name = error.name || null;
const time = new Date().toLocaleString();
const message = error.message || error.toString();
const errorToSend = { name, time, message };
return errorToSend;
```

I have called a function to check if it's a JSON or not, but it returns false.

```
IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Because JSON is a string, not an object

Comment: How do you call `IsJsonString`

Comment: I called it by IsJsonString(errorToSend)

Comment: `errorToSend` is _not a string_

Answer (score 3):

JSON is a data serialization format, which happens to look similar to the javascript syntax to create an object.  However, javascript objects are not JSON.

To encode a javascript object as JSON, you can call `JSON.stringify(myObject)`, which will convert it into its string JSON representation.

Answer (score 1):

> I have called a function to check if it's a JSON or not, but it returns false.

You have the explanation right there in your function name:

```
IsJsonString(str)
```

If you call IsJsonString on `errorToSend`

```
const errorToSend = { name, time, message };
```

it will return `false`, because

```
"This is a string"

{ but, this, is, not }
```

Comment: The same way you would check whether 3.14159 is an integer: **you don't need to**. You want to *have a JSON representation* of `errorToSend`, you accept @SamDufel's answer. Now you must ask yourself: do you need a JSON string, or do you need a serializable object? You can have both, but you must choose one. Since you're having trouble now, probably you already attempted the sending of the object, which makes me think you should use `stringify`.

Comment: @EmenpyNguyen: First you need to understand _what JSON is_.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand *[what JSON is](http://www.json.org/)*.

JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. *It is a string* representation of a Javascript object. When people say *"JSON Object"* (and many people do) they are confusing the issue. There is no such thing as a *"JSON Object"*. There is JSON (which is a string) and there are Javascript objects (which are not strings and not JSON).

Here `errorToSend` is a Javascript object:

```
const errorToSend = { name, time, message };
```

So it's *not* JSON. If `errorToSend` was this:

```
const errorToSend = '{"name":"null","time":"5/30/2018, 4:57:34 PM","message":"some message"}';
```

Then `errorToSend` would be JSON (because it's a string enclosed in `'`). Of course, not all strings are JSON and `IsJsonString` will tell you if *a string* is not valid JSON.

So it's not clear why you want `IsJsonString` at all. If you have an object (which you do), you can convert it to JSON with `JSON.stringify` and you'll know it's JSON, *because that's what that function does*. So it doesn't make sense to ask if it's JSON. Passing an object to `IsJsonString` will never make sense and will always return false.